# new to android - understanding the use of the service

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been going through this very [short tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/)and I am confused as to what is the function of the service. I am also confused as to what is the function of the broadcast receiver.

I tried to do some research and here is what i understand:
- services run in the background, but... i don't understand why we need something
  to run in the background to make the phone wake up at a certain time.

- I "think" the broadcast receiver acts as some kind of catcher's mit, in that
  when the pending intent is launched at a specific time, it catches it then 
  launches the service... how close am I to the truth ?

Comment: take a look on this tutorials first  https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html and this one also http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html no one can teach you better than this

Comment: i read that - but i need to know how the service is used in this specific case

Comment: i have posted what i think hope this will you to understand

Comment: -_why we need something to run in the background?_ Are you using any chat app like **WhatsApp** or **Facebook Messenger**. They notificate you if any message comes. How they can do this without a background service?

Answer (score 1):

As i think that `services` are used for long running tasks and especially in those cases that run when your `main activity` is not running.
For this functionality we can use `threads` this make us to say that a thread is created inside our activity and it can't be active outside of the our main activity,
that is the drawback that's why we have `services` .

[Document URL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: but what does the service do? what is its function ?

Comment: already mentioned in the answer .Please read the docs carefully

Comment: what is the purpose of the service for this kind of project ?

Comment: where you have to send some kind of notification to the user like for update ,newmsg.

Answer (score 0):

Services can be used to run long running tasks independent of your screen flow. For example, consider your application require to communicate with a server via socket throughout its running duration, you can start a service to handle this. Imagine that against starting the socket and making connection at the start of every activity, and clean up when that activity stops.

Services by default run in the main thread. But you can start separate threads in a service context, just like you do in an Activity. If your background task can overlap across multiple activities, then it is better to start it in a Service context because every Thread/AsyncTask created retains the context that it is running. In that case your Activity will be retained even if user navigates to another activity because a thread started from that Activity is already running. If Activity is retained, it might prevent all its views, images getting garbage collected.

What Services can't do is to directly alter UI components. For that it needs to communicate with the currently running Activity context. In short, if your non UI task does overlap the life time of a particular Activity, it is better to shift that task to a Service.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the function of the service ?

A service is a component which runs in the background without direct interaction with the user.

As the service has no user interface, it is not bound to the lifecycle of an activity.

Services are used for repetitive and potentially long running operations, i.e., Internet downloads, checking for new data, data processing, updating content providers and the like.

**TO READ:** [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

> What is the function of the broadcast receiver ?

Broadcast receivers are the second kind of component. Like services, they only exist in the background and don't interact with you directly. But unlike services, they can't stay running or perform long tasks: they exist to respond to events. And unlike activities and services, more than one broadcast receiver can be started in one go.

Each broadcast receiver can react straight away, for example by creating a notification, or it can start a service or an activity to take further action. As soon as the broadcast receiver has handled the event, it is stopped and will not run again until another similar event is broadcast.

**TO READ:** [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

> I don't understand why we need something to run in the background to
>   make the phone wake up at a certain time ?

We don't want that the application should necessarily be in the foreground to wake the phone up. 
Moreover we want notifications in the background.

We started the service. Now even if we close the application, you can get the phone wake up notification. This is so useful.

Services are great to interact with a user through notifications (*a way of alerting a user about an event that he needs to be informed about or even take some action on getting that information*).  Many a time, applications will need to run processes for a long time without any intervention from the user, or very rare interventions. These background processes need to keep running even when the phone is being used for other activities / tasks. 
To accommodate for such a requirement, android has introduced the `"Service"` component.

It runs in the background until it stops itself. This means that a service could be keeping your phone awake (*using a wake lock*), running down the battery, or using lots of network data, without anything showing on the screen.

> I "think" the broadcast receiver acts as some kind of catcher's mit,
>   in that when the pending intent is launched at a specific time, it
>   catches it then launches the service... how close am I to the truth ?

Correct, they are meant to respond to an intent (*usually one sent by a service or a system event*), do something, and be done. When an intent is broadcast via sendBroadcast, it will be sent to all receivers that have matching intent filters.

Answer (score -2):

Service - is a component of android, which runs in the background with out any UI. By default service will run in Main thread only.

Thread - is not android component, but still one can use thread to do some background task. Using thread in place of service is discouraged

Comment: i understand what services functions are, but what is the service specifically doing in this tutorial? and what is the broadcast receiver doing ?

Comment: Broadcast is different thing it executes the code without any user interaction eg:low battery.service is run the code backgroung.just like thread.but it runs on main thread.when coming to normal threads service has more priority eg:-when memory android o.s kills some background running task.at that time background running threads kills first then it comes to the services.